# ¿Cómo mantener los márgenes en paginas responsivas con elementos de diferentes tamaños?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Lo que pasa es que tengo un problema con mi pagina responsiva: cuando tengo la resolución de `1280px` esta muy bien los elementos, pero cuando la cambio de `1280px` para arriba se descuadran. ¿Cómo podría hacer para mantener los elementos con los márgenes sin que se dañe el estilo de la pagina?, aquí les muestro dos imágenes con las diferentes tipo de resoluciones:

Aquí sale bien el estilo de `1280px`:

[image: Aqui sale bien el estilo de 1280px]

Pero aquí, cuando cambio a una mayor resolución de `2560px` o mayor, los márgenes de los textos se descuadran. ¿Cómo haría para mantener ese mismo orden?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<section class="patria">
      <div class="patria__contenido">
        <h1 class="patria__contenido-title">De patria a patria</h1>
        <h2 class="patria__contenido-subtitle">
          Un viaje épico de Kentucky a Burundi pasando por Gales y Ucrania
        </h2>
        <img
          class="patria__contenido-image"
          src="imagenes/kalegin-michail-179870-unsplash.png"
          alt="ciudad"
        />
      </div>
    </section>
```

mi **CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px)
.introduccion__contenido {
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.introduccion__contenido-title {
width: 1017px;
height: 116px;
margin: auto;
font-size: 54px;
margin-top: 75px;
}

.introduccion__contenido-text {
width: 720px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 11%;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Muestra un [mre]

Comment: Sería bueno si adjuntaras algún **código reproducible**... de lo contrario, imposible ayudarte...

Comment: seguramente la primer parte tiene un centrado que la segunda parte no

Comment: Ahi coloque el codigo amigos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidentemente tu problema se encuentra en el `margin-left: 11%;` de `.introduccion__contenido-text`, el cual es distinto a al `margin:auto` del titulo

Sin embargo, intuyo que tu problema es otro y tiene relación al uso de los media query.

Los Media Query deberían ser el ultimo recurso a emplear para hacer un página responsiva, de lo contrario es casi como desarrollar 4 página distintas (una por cada resolución) y la idea es siempre trabajar menos.

En lugar de usar de usar Media Query para todo, te recomiendo usar funciones tales como:

- min
- max
- minmax
- clamp

Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes la típica página con un contenido centrar y unos márgenes a ambos lados, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí podríamos decir que `contenido` tuviera un ancho de `1000px` y si la resolución fuera menor que tratara de ocupar hasta el 90% de la resolución. Para esto usamos `min`

```css
html,body{
 margin:0;
}
body{
  background-color:gray;
}

.content{
  background-color:#99D9EA;
  height:100vh;
  
  margin:auto;
  width: min(90%, 1000px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 <section class="patria">
      <div class="patria__contenido">
        <h1 class="patria__contenido-title">De patria a patria</h1>
        <h2 class="patria__contenido-subtitle">
          Un viaje épico de Kentucky a Burundi pasando por Gales y Ucrania
        </h2>
        <img
          class="patria__contenido-image"
          src="imagenes/kalegin-michail-179870-unsplash.png"
          alt="ciudad"
        />
      </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Como aclaración, no digo que los media query no se deberían emplear, solo digo que deben ser el último recurso. En general, para todas las reglas relativas a la dimensión es posible usar las funciones antes mencionadas en lugar de las media query.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo te agradesco mucho por tomarte tu tiempo y darme esta explicacion de verdad te lo agradesco

Comment: Es muy buena esa tecnica me sirvio bastante gracias